# JSON C++ segmentation fault when parsing

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I want to use jsoncpp for parsing JSON keys and values from a file, using similar code as in [this example](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/old.html).

My code:

```html
        Json::Value root;
        Json::Reader reader;
        ifstream test("example2.json",ifstream::binary);
        bool success=reader.parse(test,root,false);
        if(!success){
            cout<<"Failed to parse received reply from DYAMAND\n"<<reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
            return;
        }


        string id = root["id"];
        cout<<id<<"\n";
```

Very simple code, yet I can't find out how to solve this error. None of the suggested approaches for segfaults when reading from files seem to work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: example2.json is not found ?

Comment: No, that's the strange part. It does print the id (the last line of code) and then exits with a segmentation fault.

Comment: @spiralstatic 1) `string id = root[id];`  We don't  know what `id` is.  2)  Your code also goes ahead and executes this line even though `success` could be false.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add "" when simplifying my original code. Id is a string and is a json key in the file example2.
Your second remark is also true but that is not where it goes wrong.
The segmentation fault seems to come from the reader.parse statement but I can't see why as I almost literally copied the code from the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You say the code is outputting the id, which can only happen if `parse()` is not crashing. But you also say the segfault is happening in `parse()`.  You cannot have to both ways. Unless `parse()` is swallowing the segfault internally, and the only way you are seeing it happen is because you are running inside a debugger.  If so, then just ignore it. What does the segfault actually say? If the segfault is after the output, then it is not in `parse()`. Sounds more like it might be the `Json::Value` or `Json::Reader` destructor instead.

Comment: That is what confuses me as well, though the segfault also occurs if I only keep the first 4 lines of the code. So your suggestion seems plausible.. But then I have no clue what to change...

I am using codeblocks and just get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".